# Does creating a new library and syncing it result in deletion of existing content?

Tags: iphone, itunes, sync

I sync my iPhone via iTunes from data stored in my external data. All of my data ( ie, music, iTunes libraries etc) are stored in the external drive.

Now my external drive isn't powering on due to power adapter issues. What I'm wondering, is, if I create a new library and use that library to sync to my iPhone, will my existing content on the iPhone get deleted ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you sync your iPhone with a fresh copy of iTunes it will delete those data in your iPhone. The only solution(in fact the best :) ) solution would be this,

**Step1:** Download **[Diskaid](http://www.digidna.net/diskaid/)** [this will let you use your iPhone in disk mode just like iPods

**Step2:** Change your sync mode to Manually-Sync before connect to your iTunes.

**Step3:** Run Diskaid and transfer all your music you want to add to iTunes to your computer first.

**Step4:** Now you would have got your iTunes to what it used to be & you can change sync to automatically & use it as you always would

Comment: Thank,s I'll try this and update. What about my apps ?

Comment: you can use iPhoneexplorer[http://code.google.com/p/iphonebrowser/] to backup virtually anything u want from ur iPhone.